# Setting a timeout on synchronous file write without wasting microseconds with time()

Tags: c, time, timer, milliseconds, seconds

I'm currently interfacing my PC with a microcontroller that is very sensitive with timing. In fact, I'll be lucky if I have a couple dozen microseconds to play with between sending the last byte and waiting for a byte in return.

What I am trying to do on the PC side is send the data to the microcontroller as fast as possible. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define TIMEOUT 5 //give the PC 5 seconds

int main(){
  int nwrite=0;
  int fd=open("/dev/ttyS0",O_NOCTTY | O_WRONLY); //open port
  if (fd > -1){
    int start=time(NULL); //start clock
    while (time(NULL)-start < TIMEOUT && nwrite == 0){
      nwrite=write(fd,"\n",1); //try outputting enter
      if (nwrite < 0){
        close(fd); //close file because writing returned error
        printf("Write Error");
        return -1;
      }
    }
    close(fd); 
    if (nwrite != 0){
       printf("Byte sent out");
    }
  }else{
    printf("Bad file");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Even though this does the job, it doesn't do it fast enough. Here's my strace of the program from open to close:

```
13:22:04.160431 open("/dev/ttyS0", O_WRONLY|O_NOCTTY) = 3
13:22:04.160738 time(NULL)              = 1558545724
13:22:04.160913 time(NULL)              = 1558545724
13:22:04.161088 write(3, "\n"..., 1)    = 1
13:22:04.161278 time(NULL)              = 1558545724
13:22:04.161450 close(3)                = 0
```

I noticed that those time commands take at least 100 microseconds each to process. Is there a different function I can use in place of time() to abort a write sequence if a timeout occurred? But that function needs to execute faster than the time() function.

Comment: Have you looked into the `select()` function?

Comment: Have you tried using `clock` instead of `time`? You can calculate how much TIMEOUT is in cycles and use that instead.

Comment: sorry, but why do you need to call time? trying to send as fast as possible does not need a time... I don't get the question...

Comment: You are only sending 1 byte at time, can you send a whole message? The UART should be able to hold at least 2 bytes: one being shifted, another in the output register.

Comment: I am able to do that because my target hardware waits to receive the whole message. I'll look into the clock function to see if it helps